# Prove a function is Riemann integrable on an interval - Homework

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f_n : [a,b] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a sequence of bounded Riemann integrable functions on $[a,b]$ and let $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a bounded function such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} d(f_n,f) = 0$ where $d(f_n,f)=sup[|f_n(x)-f(x)|:a \le x \le b]=0.$

Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and that

$\int_{a}^{b}fdx = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{a}^{b}f_ndx$.

I need to show this using the Riemann integrability criterion, that for every $\epsilon \gt 0, \exists$ a partition $\mathcal P$, s.t. $U(f,\mathcal P) - L(f,\mathcal P) \lt \epsilon.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\epsilon$, there is $N$ such  that $d(f_n,f)<\frac{(b-a)\epsilon}3$ for all $n>N$. For each such $n$ and any $\mathcal P$, conclude that $U(f,\mathcal P)<U(f_n,\mathcal P)+\frac\epsilon 3$ and $L(f,\mathcal P)>L(f_n,\mathcal P)-\frac\epsilon 3$. Hence for suitable $\mathcal P$ (namely with $U(f_n,\mathcal P)-L(f_n,\mathcal P)<\frac\epsilon 3$) we find that $U(f,\mathcal P)-L(f,\mathcal P)<\epsilon$. This shows integrability. 
Moreover, $$L(f_n,\mathcal P)-\frac\epsilon 3<L(f,\mathcal P) \le \int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx\le U(f,\mathcal P)<U(f_n,\mathcal P)+\frac\epsilon 3$$
and
$$ L(f_n,\mathcal P) \le \int_a^bf_n(x)\,\mathrm dx\le U(f_n,\mathcal P)$$
imply that 
$$ \left|\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx-\int_a^bf_n(x)\,\mathrm dx\right|<U(f_n,\mathcal P)-L(f_n,\mathcal P)+\frac\epsilon 3<\frac23\epsilon$$
and hence 
$$ \int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^bf_n(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that given $f$ supported on a compact set is Riemann integrable iff f is continuous except possibly on a set of measure 0.
Also the union of countable measure zero sets is still measure zero.
given ${f_n} \to f$ is sup norm s.t each $f_n$ is integrable implies that each $f_n$ is continous except possibly on a set of measure zero and this implies that $f$ is also continous ecxept possibly on a set of measure 0 namely the union of points $x$ that there is m s.t $f_m$ is not continous at $x$.
to read more [click](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.math.drexel.edu/%7Etolya/Lebesgue%2520criterion%2520for%2520Riemann%2520integrability.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjizO7hwdv9AhWYxwIHHQwrD40QFnoECAAQAw&usg=AOvVaw39ygaXcV6L-7ZqZhPCCJHW) this.